# Haskell Aeson JSON Object inside JSON Array

Tags: json, haskell, aeson

I am trying to convert a JSON String into an ADT

This is my ADT:

```
data UserList = UserList
  { userListUsers :: [UserId] }
```

This is my `FromJSON` instance for `UserList`:

```
instance FromJSON UserList where
  parseJSON (Object o) = UserList
    <$> ((o .: "relationships") >>= (.: "users") >>= (mapM (.: "id")))
```

And finally this is my JSON String:

```
{
  "relationships": { 
    "users": [
      { "type": "User","id": "8" }
    ]
  }
}
```

My **Yesod** server is giving `400 Bad Request`, without any further help, I think I may not be converting the `users` array correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to use `fromPathPiece`, I changed to do-notation to make it prettier:

```
instance FromJSON UserList where
  parseJSON (Object o) = do  
    r <- o .: "relationships"
    u <- r .: "users"
    ids <- forM u $ \x -> do
      id <- x .: "id"
      return $ fromJust . fromPathPiece $ id
    return $ UserList ids
```

Answer (score 3):

**Update**

Your parser is fine as you can test with the code below. Your implementation is the same as the one I wrote with do-notation.

**Original Answer**

This should work:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Data.Aeson
import Data.Stringable
import Control.Monad

type UserId = String

data UserList = UserList
  { userListUsers :: [UserId] }
  deriving (Show)

instance FromJSON UserList where
  parseJSON (Object o) = 
    do  r <- o .: "relationships"
        u <- r .: "users"
        idents <- forM u $ \x -> x .: "id"
        return $ UserList idents

test = do
  contents <- readFile "in"
  let e = eitherDecode (toLazyByteString contents) :: Either String UserList
  print e
```

Comment: Thanks, changing my code to do-notation some way helped me to realise what I was missing (`fromPathPiece`).